# RxJava onNext method for Logcat and toast

Tags: android, multithreading, observable, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am new into RxJava.

I am leaning by online resources and implement it.
I am trying to code very simple stuff but i am getting some issues.

```
var animalobservable: Observable<String> = Observable.just("Ant", "Bee", "Cat", "Dog", "Fox")
var animalObserver: Observer<String> = getAnimalObserver()

animalobservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
    .debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(animalObserver)
```

And i do some stuff in onNext method.

```
private fun getAnimalObserver(): Observer<String> {
    return object : Observer<String> {
        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            Log.d("OnSubscibe", "onSubscribe")
        }

        override fun onNext(s: String) {
            Log.d("OnNext", "Name: $s")
            Toast.makeText(context, "Name : $s", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Log.e("OnError", "onError: " + e.message)
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
            Log.d("OnComplete", "All items are emitted!")
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem** is when I print some code into Logcat it works fine. Data emitted one by one properly.

But when I toast it instead of Logcat it only emits last data "fox".

I want to know what's issue is going on for toast and logcat. I am assuming it happens because of threading but I am not getting why it happens.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see last toast because the toasts are immediately show sequentially and with same timing on each other, only we can see the last toast.

but if you want to add a delay between every emitting item, concat `animalobservable` with an observable with interval like this:

```
 animalobservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
        .concatMap { animal ->
            Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(1)
                .map { animal }
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(animalObserver)
```

Comment: I remove debounce(). It behaves the same.  The issue is, it emits all items in logcat and emits only last item when I toast it.

Comment: Because the toasts are immediately show sequencally and witg same timing on each other, only we can see the last toast.

Comment: Yes, now I understand logic. But still getting the problem with debounce(). How can I achieve an interval between toast?

Comment: My answer has been edited and added code. check it out

Comment: Thanks @beigirad. It works and i got clear idea, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing from

```
Schedulers.trampoline()
```

to

```
Schedulers.io()
```

since `trampoline` is usually used in testing (unittest/UItest)

EDIT:

ok, when I reread this, just like @beigirad mentioned below, it's because of your `debounce`. For logging, it's running very fast so all values can be printed within 3 seconds. However, for `Toast`, it's much slower so the time expires and it emits your last result.

If you want to do intervals between `onNext`, you can write like this

```
animalobservable
    .interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(animalObserver)
```

Comment: I have tried with trampoline() and even Executor for performing in a new thread.  But no luck. I am getting the same results.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bach vu but we cant directly access the interval method.